# Laravel 5.4 Multiple SqlServer Connections with DBLib FreeTDS 8.0

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, freetds

OS: debian/contrib-jessie64
SQL Server 2014 Express
PHP 5.6
Laravel 5.4

Using tinker can run queries on different connections, but in "browser mode" can't connect to multiple connections.

I have this in some controller:

```
    $this->saveToAnotherConnection();

    $row = \Contoso\Apartment::findOrNew($this->request['ApartmentID']);
    $row->fill($this->request->all());
    $row->save();
```

saveToAnotherConnection function opens a PDO connection but throws exception:

```
    $this->connection = new \PDO("dblib:host=10.0.1.11;dbname=Contoso", "sa", "sa sa ya tu sa! ya tu sa!");
```

Exception message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

I'm not using Laravel Database config because I'm using a library that receive the $this->connection instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange, but it seems that dblib does not recognize my server address or SQLServer instance...really strange.

Setting a DSN works for me. Edit /etc/freetds/freetds.conf and going to the end of the file and place this

```
[ms-sql]
host = 10.0.1.11
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

Where your DSN name is between brackets.

Then, connect to your SQLServer with this:

```
 $this->connection = new \PDO("dblib:host=ms-sql;dbname=Contoso", "sa", "sa sa ya tu sa! ya tu sa!");
```

That worked for me, if problem persist try to remove and install again.